# WordPress theme behaving bad

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hope you all are doing great since last few days i am facing an issue with my WordPress site this is a plugin or theme i am not sure but the file is in theme which throws error of undefined function

because of this error i am not able to open my customize menu from wordpress admin panel

and once i commented the code line where this code exists it start working but widgets does not work properly like if i enable social icons in widgets i wont be able to disable them and save settings here is the code i have commented.

```
$jobcareer_opt_array = array(
            'name' => esc_html__('Title', 'jobcareer'),
            'desc' => '',
            'hint_text' => '',
            'echo' => true,
            'field_params' => array(
                'std' => esc_attr($jobcareer_widget_title),
                /*'id' => cs_allow_special_char($this-
>get_field_id('title')),*/
                'classes' => '',
                /*'cust_id' => cs_allow_special_char($this-
>get_field_name('title')),*/
                /*'cust_name' => cs_allow_special_char($this-
>get_field_name('title')),*/
                'return' => true,
                'required' => false
            ),
        );
```

Comment: what is the name of the theme ?

Comment: Its JobCareer WordPress theme

Answer (score 1):

May be there is some version conflict between the theme and Codestar plugin. You can ask your theme's developer for that. Or as a temporary solution just remove cs_allow_special_char function and use its parameter insteaad. For example replace

cs_allow_special_char($this->get_field_name('title'))

with

$this->get_field_name('title')

and it should work then.

I checked the plugin's source, that function doesn't do any critical operation:

```
function cs_allow_special_char($input = ''){
    $output  = $input;
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: When i un-comment this code, widget section stopped working, and I am no more able to customize from appearance.

Comment: Uncomment it, but remove cs_allow_special_char() functions before. Instead of 'id' => cs_allow_special_char($this->get_field_id('title')) and so on, use just 'id' => $this->get_field_id('title')),

Comment: If also that version gives an error, it means there is something broken there.